# 「この笑顔なくしていいの？」 on a board by the road (photo)

Tags: meaning, culture

This is a board by the road (similar to [tobidashibōya](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B3%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97%E5%9D%8A%E3%82%84)).

It should mean "shall I stop smiling?" but seeing this I am not even sure.

Does it really mean that? Why? Is it a warning for drivers? Is it a "manner" reminder for children? Does it relate to some preconception of 笑顔 or a smiling girl? Or is it something uniquely odd?

[image: この笑顔なくしていいの？]

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is targeted to adults. The board says "Is it OK if you lost this (=the girl's) smile?" rather than "Can I stop this (=my) smile?" In other words, I think the board basically says "Don't do  **[that]** if you care for this smile."

But I can't tell what the board actually wants to stop. I bet the average reaction from native speakers is just like yours, "え、この看板、どういう意味?"

This is my speculation but if this is on a high-traffic road, perhaps it means "stop speeding, drive carefully". If I saw the same board in [富士の樹海](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aokigahara), I would interpret it as "stop committing suicide".

Comment: ほんまに「え、この看板どういう意味？」ですよね・・・「事故ったら家族が悲しむぞ！」とかいうことでしょうかね・・・でも絵の女の子はランドセルをしょってるように見えなくもない。。。

Comment: 公園とかで見つかったら「子供をちゃんと見張ってください」とかいういみで読むはず。
こういう意味不明な警告看板は日本に限らないみたい　―　ノルウェーの国道のそばに、悲しい女の子の顔と「制限速度を超えていますか？」というメッセージの看板がある。なぜか人は「気をつけろ！」とかはっきり言いたくないらしい。（それだけで足りないかな）

Comment: It was anything but a high-traffic road. [Here you can see](https://www.google.co.jp/maps/@35.0759079,135.2268902,3a,75y,109.08h,82.6t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s1py5bFQKBHnjrANxZLl9Gw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) where it was and what it looks like in reality. My first thought was rather: child abuse or kidnapping. Although if you turn around in Street View, there are two tobidashi-boards at this junction.

Comment: @macraf Just a guess, but I feel that two tobidashi-boards on the road of this size is already unnatural. Maybe there was a tragic accident in this place?